# Empty records in tableselect drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

Hi i m creating a tableselect similar to users table in drupal 7. I am getting empty message displayed on the screen 'No plugins available.' even though the records are being fetch in the array. Here my code

```
function massignite_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['massig/manage'] = array(
'page callback' => 'massignite_selector',
'file' => 'manage.inc',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
}

function massignite_selector() {
include('massrpc.php');
$header = array(
'plugin' => t('Plugin'),
'status' => t('Status'),
);

$params = array(
'username' => "foo",
'password' => "bar",
);
$pluginsRecords = xmlGetPlugins($params);
foreach ($pluginsRecords as $key=>$plugin) {
 $options[$key] = array(
  'plugin' => $plugin['Name'],
  'status' =>  $plugin['is_active']?'Activated':'Deactivated',
);
}
$form['table'] = array(
'#type' => 'tableselect',
'#header' => $header,
'#options' => $options,
'#empty' => t('No plugins available.'),
'#multiple' => TRUE,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Activate'),
);
$form['pager'] = array('#markup' => theme('pager'));
return $form;

}
```

I followed the tutorial given [here](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/themeing-drupal-7-forms-tables-checkboxes-or-radios). Any help will be apreciated

Edit:- Solved it!!. Apparently the i incorrectly invoked my function by menu_hook. THe correct way to do it is like this.

```
function massignite_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['massig/manage'] = array(
'title' => 'Plugins',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',                             
'page arguments' => array('massignite_table_form'),
'file' => 'manage.inc',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Comment: Presumably your `xmlGetPlugins()` function is causing that, I'd start there.

Comment: well the key given in foreach loop was not numeric that was one of the issue. But still i can only view records when i assign option directly to form and the check boxes are not displayed:-
foreach ($options as $option) {
  array_push($form['plugins'], $option);
  }

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a real form in your custom module, using hook_formID_form,

see this [tutorial](https://drupal.org/node/1419390)